# Avoid first column of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following data frame and I want to assign each value to a bin,

```
                                                                                 title
1                                        MotorolaROID RAZR MAXX 4G Android Phone Black 32GBVerizon Wireless.jpg^HTC EVO 4G 1GB White  Sprint  Smartphone.jpg
2 MotorolaROID RAZR MAXX 4G Android Phone Black 32GBVerizon Wireless.jpg^NEW 4 0 Android 2 3 Unlocked Quad Bands GPS Bluetooth Wifi Smart Cell phone G10.jpg
3                 MotorolaROID RAZR MAXX 4G Android Phone Black 32GBVerizon Wireless.jpg^Motorola Droid X2 Verizon BAD ESN GOOD Condition 100 Functional.jpg
4                                      MotorolaROID RAZR MAXX 4G Android Phone Black 32GBVerizon Wireless.jpg^UNLOCKED Huawei Ideos S7 Tablet Smartphone.jpg
5                          MotorolaROID RAZR MAXX 4G Android Phone Black 32GBVerizon Wireless.jpg^Apple iPhone 4 16GB Black  AT&T  Smartphone  MC318LLA .jpg
6                         MotorolaROID RAZR MAXX 4G Android Phone Black 32GBVerizon Wireless.jpg^Apple iPhone 4 16GB Black  Factory Unlocked  Smartphone.jpg
      column1   column2       column3   column4   column5       column6    column7
1       0.978     0.635        0.973   0.7619048 0.6383881    0.8339921 0.06666667
2       0.343     0.702        0.990   0.2623762 0.6150583    0.9285714 0.04166667
3       0.984     0.675        0.712   0.7056277 0.6770944    0.5612648 0.00000000
4       0.798     0.648        0.931   0.4090909 0.5864263    0.8571429 0.00000000
5       0.898     0.709        0.993   0.5000000 0.6951220    0.9328063 0.05882353
6       0.898     0.709        0.993   0.5000000 0.6951220    0.9328063 0.06250000
```

When I tried to run the following line I get an error Error in `cut.default(newX[, i], ...) : 'x' must be numeric` I know this is because my first column is the title column. How can I execute this by ignoring the first column.

```
df_bin <- apply(df, 2, cut, c(-Inf, seq(0.5, 1, 0.1), Inf), labels=0:7)
```

Answer (score 5):

Apply over 'all but the first column' by excluding it via a `-1` count:

```
  df_bin <- apply(df[,-1], 2, cut, c(-Inf, seq(0.5, 1, 0.1), Inf), labels=0:7)
```

The key here is `df[,-1]` versus your `df`.

Comment: Yes. You know this but the questioner may need to know: Only atomic vectors are passed by `apply`. (No factors, Dates, or mixed type vectors.)

Comment: Now I have entire dataframe as strings, previously column data was integers and I could do any arithmatics on column but looks like I cant do it anymore.